# 1999 Dodge Durango won't start after backwards jump

Tags: electrical, security, battery-drain

1999 dodge durango will turn over but not start after a friend put jumper cables on backwards.when i try to start vehicle security light blinks ,flashers and dashboard light blinks for approx a min but security light never goes off.none of the.gauges on dash board work.power lock switch on driver and passenger door only unlock/lock back gate.battery is good but after jumping it off when i remove cables battery drains down quickly seems like a short to the battery.interior lights,air conditioner both work radio comes on but no music plays

Comment: You need to check the open circuit voltage of the battery first.  A "backwards jump" as you described it, may have done irreparable harm to your battery.  I doubt there is more damage than that, but the very fact you needed a jump (good, bad, backwards or otherwise) makes me suspect you need a new battery.

Comment: With the security light on, it sounds like the vehicle ignition is locked out. You may be able to do something with this by disconnecting the battery for 30 minutes to reset all of the electronics. Give it a whirl and see if it will reset. You very easily *could* have fried a vital electronic part. I've seen it happen before. One of the main things to look at after starting is the alternator. For the radio, check if there is an amplifier in the system, which may have had a fuse blown. Heck, first stop should be checking *all of your fuses!* Great place to start, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Get your battery sorted first, if the battery dead (which is very possibly melted), when the battery is full or replaced, if it doesn't work, get OBD2 scanner to it or ask for a help in garage. Your ECU might be burned... :(

Comment: Shouldn't speculation be a comment

Comment: It is solid advice. If you want to say its speculation then you might as well say that for 90% of the answers on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Start by either replacing or having the battery tested and fully charged. A low battery in itself will cause many no start conditions.

The security light blinking **while or after cranking** is normal do not make any assumptions based on this.

To test the immobilizer do this: Insert key and turn it to the ON position (do not crank) What does security light do?

Blink = Key is no longer accepted by skim.

Solid = Skim accepts key but can not verify with PCM.

Solid for a few seconds and then goes out = Skim accepts transponder and verify's with PCM. This system is ok.

*(skim is the immobilizer ecu)*

If the light blinks AND  your car only cranks, then you have more issue's then just the immobilizer. I say this because chrysler, dodge and jeeps WILL run for 3 seconds and cut off up to 3 times and then they will no longer crank at all when the immobilizer is active.

If it was me I would first try to communicate with PCM using a decent scan tool.

If it connects I would check available information (like VIN and calibration data) sometimes you can see corruption of the software which is more common then one may think (you will usually see weird symbols instead of the proper data if it was).

If it does not communicate then I would check all fuses, relays and grounds that supply the pcm. If they are good I would replace or have the pcm repaired.

For what its worth, I do a lot of pcm repair and commonly see damaged pcm's from reverse polarity.